# Can someone help me understand why an auto-identity (int) is bad when using NHibernate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I've been seeing a lot of commentary (from an NHibernate perspective) about using Guid as opposed to an int (and presumably auto-id in the database), with the conclusion that using auto-identity breaks the UoW pattern.

[This post](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2008/12/identity-never-ending-story.html) has a short description of the issue, but it doesn't really tell me "why" it breaks the pattern (unless I'm misunderstanding which is likely the case.

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few major reasons.

- Using a `Guid` gives you the ability to identify a single entity across many databases, including six relational databases with the same schema but different data, a document database, etc. This becomes important any time you have more than one single place where data goes - and that means your case too: you have a dev database and a prod database, right?
- Using a `Guid` gives NHibernate the ability to batch more statements together, perform more database work at the very end of the unit of work / transaction, and reduce the total number of roundtrips to the database, increasing performance as well as conferring other benefits.

Comment:

Random `Guid`s do not create poor indexes - natively, they create poor *clustered* indexes. There are two solutions.

- Use a partially sequential `Guid`. With NHibernate, this means using the `guid.comb` id generator rather than the `guid` id generator. `guid.comb` is partially sequential for good performance, but retains a very high degree of randomness.
- Have your `Guid` primary key be a `nonclustered` index, and put a clustered index on another auto-incrementing column. You may decide to map this column, in which case you lose the benefit of better batching and fewer roundtrips, but you regain all the benefits of short numbers that fit easily in a URL. Or you may decide not to map this column and have it remain completely within the database, in which case you gain better performance for `Guid`s as primary keys as well as better performance for NHibernate doing fewer roundtrips.

Comment: But non-sequential GUID will create poor indexes, is there a good way to deal with this?

Answer (score 3):

My take would be that the key breaking factor is that getting the auto-incremented value requires an actual write to the database, which nHibernate would have deferred or possibly never performed.

Answer (score 1):

Using identity and in a parent-child scenario the database has round trip the database to get the ID of a parent so that it can associate the child correctly. This means that the parent has to be committed at this time. Should there be a problem with the child you would then need to delete the parent in order to exit the UoW correctly.